# Best practices for link logging in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, analytics

Basically, `onclick` will trigger exclusively on left clicks.

Most places recommend `onmouseup`, because it triggers on left, middle, and right clicks.  The right clicks can of course be filtered out.  However, it is still possible to generate false positives from `onmouseup` by left or middle click dragging from text to the link.

Is there a more direct way in JavaScript that will be triggered if and only if an external link is followed?  Or is `onmouseup` the only practical solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something with `window.onbeforeunload`. Have it call a function that does your bidding. What are you wanting to detect?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `onmouseup` only.
For `onbeforeunload`; this method is not supported in Opera. Rest all leading browsers supports it. There is no public specification for it too. `onbeforeunload` was introduced by Microsoft IE 4 and has subsequently been copied by other browsers.

Comment: Yeah, both approaches have their drawbacks. Per the OP: "However, it is still possible to generate false positives from onmouseup by left or middle click dragging from text to the link."

Comment: It also looks like onbeforeunload would miss the use-cases of tabbed browsing.